# Ruby convert string 1/1/2014 to date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to convert a string into a date object. My string is in the format "8/19/2013", and I need to return a valid ruby date object so I can find the earliest and latest date from the array with something like date_array.min/max.

## Update

I am building an array that looks like...

```
  student_start_dates[row["person_id"]] << Date.new(row["start_date"])
```

...so this worked...

```
  student_start_dates[row["person_id"]] << row[Date.strptime("start_date", "%d/%m/%Y")]
```

Comment: You're missing a slash in your format. Also, you're not putting your variable name in quotes, are you?

Comment: Opps...I should have caught that. Updating answer...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
require 'time'    
Date.strptime('9/19/2013', '%m/%d/%Y')
```

The result is a `Date` object.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but OP said he wanted a Date object.

Comment: change `require 'time'` to `require 'date'`

Comment: Hmm, so now you've modified your answer to be exactly the same as @Arup's. *Now* I'm downvoting.

Comment: @ArupRakshit viewing the edited versions of this answer does not show any "Date.parse"...

Comment: @MrYoshiji Because he removed it within **5 mins**.. You know the magic of **5 mins** in SO..right ? :-)

Comment: @MrYoshiji *history* started after 5 mins, you posted any answer, any change within 5 mins, while you are posting, will not be recorded..

Comment: @Agis I don't need to see the edit history, as I've been here. Edit #4, which was retracted within the grace period, was identical.

Comment: I think you're confusing me with someone else. I don't care who thought of it first; I don't care who had zero typos first. I care that future SO guests will get the best possible answers and explanations. Currently, your answer differs by one word. If you explain the subtle difference in a way that benefits future visitors, I will remove my downvote.

Answer (score 3):

Do as :

```
require 'date'

Date.strptime("9/19/2013","%m/%d/%Y")
```